# bootstrap hides my field or it reduce its width

Tags: css

I have a webpage utilizing the current bootstrap. It displays a label and text input box part of a form.

If I include the `class="custom-control-input"` to the input text field, Bootstrap hides it. Why?

If I don't include, it shows up, but it won't fulfill the full width according to its parent div tag.

The code is:

```html
    <div class="container">
        <form class="needs-validation" novalidate action="submit_transgene_entry.php" method="post">
      <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2 mb-3">
                    <label for="comments_fieldID1">field below is shown, but won't extend full width</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-10 mb-3">
                        <input type="text" id="comments_fieldID1" name="comments_fieldName">
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2 mb-3">
                    <label for="comments_fieldID2">the following field is hidden by custom-control-input</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                        <input type="text" id="comments_fieldID2" class="custom-control-input" name="comments_fieldName">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                    <input type="submit" name='accept_transgene_entry' class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" value="Accept Transgene Entry" alt="Accept Transgene Entry"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

You can see the code in action at [this page](https://jsfiddle.net/mauricev/cohz28ue/41/)

Answer (score 1):

You must use the `form-control` class instead of `custom-control-input`. 
I've edited your fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/2orbj50v/

Answer (score 0):

Just add this in your CSS

```
#comments_fieldID1 {
  width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reason Behind Hiding this the class **"custom-control-input"** have some default css value from bootstrap like this, if you change the opacity 1 instead of 0 it will show the original field.

```
.custom-control-input {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

to make the input field full width just add this css

```
#comments_fieldID1 {
      width:100%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That may be because bootstrap 4 provide customized form elements for

1. Checkbox
2. Radio button
3. Range
4. Select
5. Upload
6. Toggle

And for these to work you have to wrap it around a `<div>` with `class="custom-control custom-checkbox"`. The following is the example if you want to use custom-checkbox. But it won't work if you replace **checkbox** with **text**

```
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-3">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck" name="example1">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck">Custom checkbox</label>
</div>
```

And for your first input box, you can simply make it's with to be 100%. Like shown below:

```
#comments_fieldID1{
   width:100%;
}
```

Comment: It turns out that once I set up classes correctly, the edit field gets sized correctly automatically.

Answer (score 0):

> **Best Answer** : Use `form-control` for your #comments_fieldID1 element

Or you can add css in your css file :

```
#comments_fieldID1 {
    width:  100%;
}
```